# HP-ALM requirement status change alert script

Tags: testing, vbscript, automation, ui-automation, alm

I am using HP-ALM 12.21.

I want to set an Email notification alert whenever status is changes to "development" of my current requirements.

Just came across some solution where you can set alert on "customize" page but in my profile "Customize" page has only password change option.

is there any vbscript for this ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have administrator rights, or you can let your administrator do it.

Then add workflow script in Customization -> Workflow -> Requirement module script -> Req_FieldChange(FieldName).

For example,

```js
Sub Req_FieldChange(FieldName)
  On Error Resume Next
  If TDConnection.UserName = "sa" Then
    If FieldName = "RQ_REQ_STATUS" Then
        Dim objReqFactory, objReq
        Set objReqFactory=TDConnection.ReqFactory
        Set objReq=objReqFactory.Item(Req_Fields("RQ_REQ_ID").Value)
        objReq.Mail "sa@hpe.com","",0,"Requirement Change Notification","The user sa changed the status of the requirement"
    End If
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

I hope my answer is helpful to you.

Thank you and regards,

Wenjuan